# AJAX PHP code with animated divs restarting with every load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Following JavaScript code is used to load the PHP page:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('.squeeze_overzicht').load('squeeze_overzicht.php');
}, 2000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. S
});
```

In the PHP script following div is set:

```
if ($LMS_info['result']['mode'] == "play")
            {   
                echo "<div class=\"squeeze_plays_badkamer\"></div>";
            }
```

Problem: The inserted div is an animated div which restarts with every load. I want it to keep rotating till the div is not shown. How to set the div without being influenced by the specific loading time set in the JavaScript?

Comment: Is putting the logic into the frontend no option? Polling is in general not the best way to structure a web application. And syncing between frontend and backend will be difficult. If you need some real-time interaction between both then consider something like WebSockets.

Comment: To my knowledge the logitech media server does not work with WebSockets. Since it is only for my magicmirror and not for an open website, polling seems ok.

I do not understand what your meen by putting the logic in the frontend? How would polling than work, assuming that also some google API are being used and have a maximum of requests a day?